# How to achieve this in Oracle query (Appending values)

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

var1 = 2 (count from a table)
var2 = 3 (count from another table)

I am writing a query

```
Select 
'Factor1 (' + var1 + ')' as NEW_FACTOR,
'Factor2 (' + var2 + ')' as ANOTHER_FACTOR
FROM SomeTable
```

ResultSet should be

Factor1 (2) Factor2 (3)

How do I append in Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the `||` operator to concatenate strings

```
SELECT 'Factor1 (' || var1 || ')' new_factor,
       'Factor2 (' || var2 || ')' another_factor
  FROM SomeTable
```

Comment: I tried and tried and only once I used the || in the past. Now I will remember forever! Thanks Justin!!